# Add LDFLAGS to newlib Makefiles

Tags: linker, makefile, ld, newlib, ldflags

I'm trying to implement the _sbrk() function in the syscalls.c file. For this I need to link newlib with my projects object file.
In newlibs root folder I did a simple

```
./configure --target=arm-elf
```

which created me a bunch of Makefiles. 
But now I don't know which Makefile I have do edit in order to change the LDFLAGS.
Without doing this I get an "undefined reference" error because the linker doesn't find the related object.
Thanks in advance for reading (and hopefully helping me out :)
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change `LDFLAGS` globally for your build then you can invoke `configure` like this:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="<yourflags>" --target=arm-elf
```

The resulting `Makefile` will use the provided flags as its `LDFLAGS`.